# How Do I Read .CSV Files From Left To Right In Order? C#

Tags: c#

I have a .csv file that has different text in different boxes(rows and columns) but I am trying to put them in my application. I can grab from the file but I can't seem to make so that row 1 is an list, row 2 is a different list, etc. I was wondering if you can help.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = filePath;
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Comma Seperated Vaule File (*.csv)|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Find Text File";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {

                    System.IO.Stream fileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();

                    string filePath = @"C:\Users\16muellerm\Desktop\examplecsv.csv";
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
                    var lines = new List<string[]>();
                    string[] Line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    //string[] completedLine = new List<string[]>();

                    int Row = 0;
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {

                        lines.Add(Line);
                        Row++;
                        //Console.WriteLine(Row);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= Line.Count() ; i++)
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text += Line[i-1];
                        }
                    }

                    var data = lines.ToArray();

                    /* using (myStream )
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory;
                        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream);
                        // Insert code to read the stream here.
                        //  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                        var lines = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        richTextBox1.Text = lines;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= lines.Count()-1; i++) {
                            var line = lines[i];
                            list.Add(lines[i].ToString());
                            list.ForEach(updateStuff);

                        }


                    }*/
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for responding.

Comment: I removed the `visual-c++` tag. This has nothing to do with `visual-c++`

Comment: How specifically is this code failing?  Also, why are you putting each row into a `List<T>`?  Generally a row corresponds to an entity of some kind, like in any tabular data set.  Why not have one single `List<T>` of a custom object and add each row to that list as an instance of that object?

Comment: you should probably add sr.ReadLine in while loop as well

Comment: Please add a few example lines of the input file, and what you expect to do with the values.

Answer (score 3):

Is this an option?

```
File.ReadAllLines( fileName ).Select( x => x.Split( seperator ) ).ToList()
```

You'd get a list of rows, with an array of strings for each row.